# Responsiveness with Now ui kit css framework

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I Just started using Now-UI kit which is a beautiful bootstrap 4 kit . I have been using bootstrap version 4.0 and it is very responsive on any device. But i decided to use Now-UI kit for a new project but it is not being responsive on mobile devices. my app url is https://nigeriania.herokuapp.com. Can anyone look through the url on a mobile and tell me what am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems damn responsive on my mobile-sized browser. any specific bugs you got ?

Comment: It's not on mine.  Try to adjust it like does it really fit, i just want to know if my phone is deceiving me. Thanks in advance

Comment: try to swipe the website to the left. you will notice some spaces in between. Because the menu button is not showing and it's actually there. Its floating between those spaces

Comment: If you check your `figcaption` tags thats what pushing the screen, you should remove the `position: absolute` from the `section.partners .info` rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your `Proudly Supported By` Section ( I added a red border to brand titles so you can see their out of their parent )

[image]
[image]

you can add `overflow:hidden` to this sections `<div class='row'>` and see everything works well.

Good Luck

Comment: Adding `overflow: hidden` just removes the scroll, not really a 'solution' but more like a 'hacky' way to avoid the issue; I think OP needs a way to prevent that scroll to happen in the first place

Comment: But what do you think its the cause of that in case of next time?

Comment: ok so let see what is happening: figcaption has a width of 100% + 25px from both sides padding. its overflowing. just change it as following: `width:calc(100% - 50px);`